# Cannot get gridApi in Ag-Grid using React hooks in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ag-grid

I am using **function component** in react with **typescript**. Here is what my component looks like

```
const Table = (props: TableProps) => {

const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(() => {})

  const gridOptions = {
    rowData: rowData,
    columnDefs: columnDef,
    pagination: true,
  }

const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
}


  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" >
      <AgGridReact gridOptions={gridOptions} onGridReady={onGridReady}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I need to get the `gridApi` so I can use it in a handler for another component to do quick filtering.

Looking at the docs [HERE](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/grid-interface/), the recommended way is to grab the gridApi and store it in a state. Considering that I am using function component here is what I did

`const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(() => {})`

When I do this in the handler:

```
  const handleTableFilter = (filterText: string) => {
      gridApi.setQuickFilter(filterText) // error here - Property 'setQuickFilter' does not exist on type '() => void'.
  }
```

Typescript complains that  `Property 'setQuickFilter' does not exist on type '() => void'.`

I also tried the pattern recommended for Javascript [HERE](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grid-interface/) but I could not quite figure that out too.

I would appreciate some help on how to store the gridApi in my use case (Typescript, React using Function components - react hooks). If possible, I would prefer a solution where I will not have to store a function in `useState`. If not, I a fine with any solution.

Comment: Based off those docs all you need to do is `import` the grid api and render it as a react component... why do you need to store it in state? You just import it. The [third block of code](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/getting-started/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project-2) from this docs link explains it. The error in your post comes from typescript and the fact that you currently are setting the state of `gridApi` to an empty function that returns nothing. You also seem to be using `gridApi` and `setGridApi` nowhere in your component. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: See the method `somePointLater()` in doc. You must be immediately use the `gridAPI` in `handleTableFilter` before you initialize the state. That cause the issue. And also `gridAPI` is an object but you initialized the state with an empty function which is type `() => void`. Either change the type of state to `any` or import the typeof `gridAPI` from the package and set it as the type of the state.

Comment: try something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-ay1h16?file=index.js).

Comment: Another option is to do `React.useState<GridApi>()` then access it like so `gridApi?.setQuickFilter(filterText)`

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I ended up doing to get GridApi without error in Typescript ( Mike Abeln comments in the question pointed me in the right direction)

```
const Table = (props: TableProps) => {

// - - - - omitted code for column & row data from props - - - -

  const gridApiRef = useRef<any>(null); // <= defined useRef for gridApi

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [columnDef, setColumnDef] = useState<any[]>([]);

// - - - - omitted code for useEffect updating rowData and ColumnDef - - - -

  const gridOptions = {
    pagination: true,
  }

const onGridReady = (params) => {
    params.api.resetRowHeights();
    gridApiRef.current = params.api // <= assigned gridApi value on Grid ready
}

  const handleTableFilter = (filterText: string) => {
    gridApiRef.current.setQuickFilter(filterText); // <= Used the GridApi here Yay!!!!!
  }

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" >
      <AgGridReact columnDefs={columnDef} 
      rowData={rowData} 
      gridOptions={gridOptions} 
      onGridReady={onGridReady} 
      ref={gridApiRef}/> // the gridApiRef  here
    </div>
  );
};
```

Although I am seeing some performance issue on the table (the tables are huge with about 600K rows) but this answers the question on how to get GridApi and use it to filter

Comment: for me changing `const gridApiRef = useRef();` to `const gridApiRef = useRef<any>(null);` just worked

Answer (score 2):

The type for the `gridApiRef` is `<AgGridReact>` from `'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact'`.

Example:

```js
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
import { AgGridReact as AgGridReactType } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact'

// Make sure it initialize as null.
const gridApiRef = useRef<AgGridReactType>(null); 

const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [columnDef, setColumnDef] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
   fetch('url')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => setRowData(data)
}, [])


  return (
   <div className="ag-theme-alpine" >
      <AgGridReact 
         ref={gridApiRef}
         columnDefs={columnDef} 
         rowData={rowData} 
         gridOptions={gridOptions}/>
    </div>
  );
```

Here's a tutorial: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/using-ag-grid-with-react-getting-started. Not in typescript though.